# Filter real numbers that less than 1.0 in the whole list

Tags: list-manipulation

Assuming we have a list below, it has real number elements and complex numbers, how can I quickly find if the list has any Real number that its value is less than 1.0?

```
 lis = {3 Sqrt[354], Sqrt[2962], Sqrt[2746], 3 Sqrt[282], Sqrt[2338], 
  Sqrt[2146], 3 Sqrt[218], Sqrt[1786], Sqrt[1618], 27 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[
  1306], Sqrt[1162], 3 Sqrt[114], Sqrt[898], Sqrt[778], 3 Sqrt[74], 
  Sqrt[562], Sqrt[466], 3 Sqrt[42], Sqrt[298], Sqrt[226], 9 Sqrt[2], 
  Sqrt[106], Sqrt[58], 3 Sqrt[2], I Sqrt[14], I Sqrt[38], 3 I Sqrt[6],
   I Sqrt[62], I Sqrt[62], 3 I Sqrt[6], I Sqrt[38], I Sqrt[14], Sqrt[
  1.2], Sqrt[58], Sqrt[1.06], 9 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[226]}
```

I am also considering if we can find methods to filter any real or complex  numbers with specific values in any types list (e.g. there are some string elements mixed with real and complex number elements in a given list). But this could be another question and isn't necessary for my example. Please leave some advice if you interested! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would numericize first, something like `FreeQ[N @ lis, _Real?(LessThan[1])]`

Comment: One of the most straightforward: `Select[lis, Re[#] < 1 && Im[#] == 0 &]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[lis, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ@# && # < 1 & /@ lis]
```

> {}

```
Pick[lis, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ @ # && # < 5 & /@ lis]
```

> {3 Sqrt[2], 1.09545, 1.02956}

`Pick` combined with @aardvark2012's selector approach and exploiting the fact that `Negative`, `Positive`, `NonPositive` ... are `Listable`:

```
Pick[lis, NonPositive[lis - 5]]
```

> {3 Sqrt[2], 1.09545, 1.02956}

This seems to be the fastest of methods posted so far.

Comment: +1. I wonder how many "How do I select elements satisfying condition $P$?" questions the site has, all with virtually the same large set of alternatives.  BTW, I was going to use ``Developer`RealQ /@ N@lis``, but then thought better of it for some reason

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you for the upvote.  I agree re the number of questions with answers using `Pick/Select/Cases...` .  FWIW, this one is more about  specifying the condition/selector to get  Reals.

Comment: Something like `Re[x] < 1 && Im[x] == 0`, in some form or other, seems a kinda straightforward, first-guess sort of thing to try to me (almost Nasser's).

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

> how can I quickly find if the list has any Real number that its value
>   is less than 1.0?

One way might be

```
Cases[ReIm[lis],{x_,y_}/;y==0&&x<1]
(*{} *)
```

Example

```
 lis={.7, .7I .7+1, 2, 2I, 2+1 I};
 Cases[ReIm[lis],{x_,y_}/;y==0&&x<1 :> Complex[x,y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the above, you can now add any kind of checks on `x` and `y` to filter any kind of number you want. For example, to look for pure complex numbers:

```
 Cases[ReIm[lis],{x_,y_}/;x==0&&y!=0 :> Complex[x,y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To look for number with real and complex parts

```
  Cases[ReIm[lis],{x_,y_}/;x!=0&& y!=0 :> Complex[x,y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `Pick`:

```
Pick[lis, UnitStep[1 - Re@#] + I*Im@# &@N@lis, 1]
(*  {}  *)

lis2 = lis/10;
Pick[lis2, UnitStep[1 - Re@#] + I*Im@# &@N@lis2, 1]
(*  {Sqrt[29/2]/5, 3/(5 Sqrt[2]), 0.109545, Sqrt[29/2]/5, 0.102956}  *)
```

`UnitStep[1 - Re@#]` returns `1` if the real part of the number is less than `1`. And `I*Im@#` is `0` if the number is real; otherwise, it will have a nonzero imaginary part and be a number of type `Complex`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)and [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html).

```
Select[# ∈ Reals && # < 1 &]@lis
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

There appear to be no items that are both in the reals and less than one.

If you do not need the items but only the result of the test then you could place in an [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) and test the [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html).

```
If[
 Length@Select[# ∈ Reals && # < 1 &]@lis > 0,
 True,
 False]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's always `Select`:

```
Select[lis, Negative[# - 1] &]
```

[`Negative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Negative.html) is nice because it'll work on pretty much anything, but only return `True` if the argument is a negative real number. Testing it on a longer list:

```
SeedRandom[123456]
lis = RandomSample[
  Join[RandomReal[2, 10], RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 10]], 
 20];

Select[lis, Negative[# - 1] &]

(* {0.982588, 0.86323, 0.0961836, 0.963281, 0.780961, 0.225647, 0.34709} *)
```

But the question is a little ambiguous -- the phrase "how can I quickly find if the list has any Real number that its value is less than 1.0?" indicates that you don't actually care what the numbers *are*, just whether they're there or not. If that's what you're really after, you can do:

```
CountsBy[lis, Negative[# - 1] &][True]

(* 7 *)
```

As far as generalization goes, `Select` is so incredibly generalizable that it's hard to know where to start. If, say, there are strings involved in your list, these approaches still work as they are:

```
SeedRandom[123456]
lis = RandomSample[
  Join[RandomReal[2, 10], RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 10], 
   RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10]], 30]

Select[lis, Negative[# - 1] &]
CountsBy[lis, Negative[# - 1] &][True]

(* {0.0961836, 0.982588, 0.225647, 0.780961, 0.963281}
   5 *)
```